# MethodOverride - "Method Not Supported"?

Tags: haskell, middleware, yesod

```
<form method=POST _method=DELETE action=@{PostR postID} >
  <input type=submit value=Delete>
```

I'm using the `MethodOverride` middleware, but Yesod doesn't recognize this form as a `DELETE` method, instead treating it as a `POST` method, resulting in a "Method Not Supported" error message when the form is submitted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<form method=POST action=@{PostR postID}?_method=DELETE>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it working with `action=@?{(PostR postID,[("_method","DELETE")])}` but this is much more elegant.

Comment: Another option is to use `Network.Wai.Middleware.MethodOverridePost` and put a hidden input field named `_method` at the beginning.

Comment: How to use methodOverride method? Where do i need to apply it?